# Spring Solr connection with Zookeeper using jaas.conf

Tags: spring-boot, apache-zookeeper, solrj

I am migrating an existing java project to Spring Boot. It connects to Solr via Zookeeper.

It is throwing following error on startup.

```
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /clusterstate.json
```

This following configuration works on local, but on other environments Zookeeper requires some authentication (jaas.conf). How do I pass the jaas.conf to Spring Boot such that it can initialize SolrClient correctly?

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = "com.search", multicoreSupport = true)
public class SolrConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.solr.zk-host}")
    private String zkHost;

    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new CloudSolrClient(zkHost);
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient solrClient) throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrClient);
    }
}
```

**jaas.conf**

```
Client {
       org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
       username="some_username"
       password="some_password";
};
```

I tried passing credentials as environment properties of zkDigestUsername and zkDigestPassword. In this case there was no exception during Spring Boot startup, but subsequent inserts/reads to Solr is not working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by providing jaas config using the following JVM parameter.

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/zookeeper/conf/jaas.conf
```